# ResourceBundle from Java/Struts and replace expressions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts, resourcebundle

If I have a Resource bundle property file:

A.properties:

```
thekey={0} This is a test
```

And then I have java code that loads the resource bundle:

```
ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("A", currentLocale);
labels.getString("thekey");
```

How can I replace the {0} text with some value

```
labels.getString("thekey", "Yes!!!");
```

Such that the output comes out as:

```
Yes!!! This is a test.
```

There are no methods that are part of Resource Bundle to do this.  Also, I am in Struts, is there some way to use MessageProperties to do the replacement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The class you're looking for is java.text.MessageFormat; specifically, calling

```
MessageFormat.format("{0} This {1} a test", new Object[] {"Yes!!!", "is"});
```

or

```
MessageFormat.format("{0} This {1} a test", "Yes!!!", "is");
```

will return

```
"Yes!!! This is a test"
```

[Unfortunately, I can't help with the Struts connection, although [this](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=915891) looks relevant.]

Answer (score 2):

There is the class [org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.7/api/org/apache/struts/util/MessageResources.html) with various methods getMessage, some of them take arguments to insert to the actual message.

Eg.:

```
messageResources.getMessage("thekey", "Yes!!!");
```